# Is the gets() string function in C considered a bad practice?

Tags: c, gets

was reading the Head first C book and stumbled across the author saying `gets()` to be a bad practice

> `gets()` is a function that’s
>               been around for a long time.
>               But all you really need to know
>               is that you really shouldn’t
>               use it.

why is it considered a bad practice?

Comment: The `gets` function is no longer part of C.  It's so awful it was removed.

Comment: It is a function that ***CANNOT*** be safely used, because it is given a buffer of characters to write into but no maximum number of characters to read. If you provide too many characters you will end up with corruption. On no account use it; Prefer `fgets()`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: There's one safe way to use `gets`, when `stdin` is known to be a file fully under your control. However this situation is sufficiently unusual (and, I might say, artificial) not to be worth considering, and for practical purposes `gets` is *always* unsafe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    gets(buffer);
    printf("The input is %s",buffer);
}
```

When user types input of length within 99 then there is no problem. But when user types more than 99 characters it tries to write into memory it doesn't own.

The worst thing is it causes abnormal behaviour and the program terminates without any information which leaves user baffled about the current situation

An alternative way is to use `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);` function

**Update:** As pointed by @pmg : `gets()` removes newline while `fgets()` retains the new line

Comment: Try 99 not 100 (null character)

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: [`gets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gets.html) removes the newline; [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) retains it.

Comment: @pmg Wasn't aware of this further asymmetry between `fgets()` and `gets()`. I'll pull my comment.

Answer (score 4):

`gets` is prone to buffer overruns (i.e. memory corruption etc).

`fgets` over comes this by having passing in the size of the buffer