# First letter of any word after the first goes missing

Tags: c, gets, puts, fputs

I am fairly new to programming and i have done some in school, but they only taught basic functions like printf, scanf, for, while, pointers. I am making a small program that will print user input in to a file, but when the text is written into the file the first letter of every word after the first is missing and i don't know why. can somebody explain what is happening to the first letters and do so in a simple manner if you can, please and thank you for your answer.

This is the function i am using to write to the file.

```
void text(){
    int e=1;        
    puts("After a sentance press enter to continue or esc to stop");` 
    printf("Enter text now\n");
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Text.txt","w");
End:while(e==1){
    char txt[100];
    puts(gets(txt),fp);
    if(getche()=='\e')
    e=0;
    goto End;   
    }   //end of while
        fclose(fp);
    }// end of function
```

New code

```
void text(){
    int e=1;        
    puts("After ending a sentance press enter to continue or esc to stop"); 
    printf("Enter text now\n");
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Text.txt","w");
while(e==1){
    char txt[100];
    fgets(txt,100,stdin);
    fwrite(txt,sizeof(char),sizeof(txt),fp);
    if(getche()=='\e'){
        break;
    }
    else;   
    }   
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: Did you seriously use `goto`? It's bad practice. It is clear _here_, but still...

Comment: Also, why don't you use `fgets` for input and `fprintf` to write to the file?

Comment: i tried using break; but it didn't break the loop immediately

Comment: @Tim: `break` breaks the loop immediately, your `goto` does nothing, because you are going back to the beginning of the loop, the same place it would go without the `goto` anyway.

Comment: You mean like this: fprintf(fp,fgets(txt,100,stdin),"%s"); ? Didn't work

Comment: @Tim try not to use labels

Comment: Try to use `fwrite` also

Comment: Or if performence is not important for you use `fprintf`

Comment: Ok, i made it so that it breaks now insted of using goto, funny thing is i tried it before and it didn't work :)

Comment: Has your school taught you `gets`? I seriously hope not. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419866/is-the-gets-string-function-in-c-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @szczurcio no they haven't, they only taught printf and scanf for input and output.There were only around 20 hours of class and they wasted half of it.

Comment: Well, just don't use `gets`. It's so bad it was removed in the latest C revision. Instead, you can use `fgets`.

Comment: @Ehsan i tried using fwrite but it turned the text in the file gibberish `fwrite(txt,sizeof(char),sizeof(txt),fp);`. I think i am not using it i the correct way, can someone show me how it would look if i would put it in my code?

Comment: Bro you should open the file in "wb" flag coz fwrite writes into the file in a binary syntax

Comment: And before writing to the file check that the file pointer isn't `NULL`

Comment: And instead of sizeof(t) just pass the size of the txt, I mean 100.

Comment: coz sizeof(txt) returns the size of a pointer which in new systems is 4 Bytes

Comment: @Ehsan: No, `sizeof(txt)` is the size of the variable, that is of type `char[100]`, so `100` bytes. But he should probably use `strlen(txt)` because the string may be shorter. Also the check for `NULL` is useless because a local array cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: idk I have heared it returns the size of pointer I really don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many issues, but... your particular problem is that `getche()` reads one character, if it is `\e` you do something, but if it is another characters, then it is lost!

Using your functions of choice (`getche()` and `gets()`) you can do:

```
while (1)
{
    char c = getche();
    if (c == '\e')
        break;
    txt[0] = c;
    gets(txt+1);
    /* ... */
}
```

This will not remove the first character, but will fail with empty lines, I think.. I will leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I only need to break the loop with esc(`\e`) so i don't need it if the loop continues or if it breaks and i know i have many problems in the code, but i don't know exactly which commands are better for what job.

Comment: does `getche()` take the missing letter or where does it end up?

Comment: @Tim: It returns the read character. You are comparing it with `\e`, but otherwise not storing it.

Comment: you ware right, the first letter is lost because of the `getche`. I will try to take your code and put it in my program, thank you for all your help.