# Why is the while loop not working?

Tags: c

im new to c language and i am facing some problems with  my code.. I have to make a program that computes the prices for renting cars but the while loop is not functioning properly.The scanf above the while condition is %s and not %c because it wont let me give a characther when it is %c.Thank you in advance.

```
int main(){
    float skms, ekms, tkms, price;
    char catcode;
    int days;

    do{
        printf("Selected rental program:\n");
        scanf("%c",&catcode);
        printf("Enter number of days:\n");
        scanf("%d",&days);
        printf("Starting kilometers display:\n");
        scanf("%f",&skms);
        printf("Kilometers display at end of rent:\n");
        scanf("%f",&ekms);
        tkms=(ekms/10)-(skms/10);
        switch(catcode){
                case'a':
                case'A':
                    price=ammountDueA(days, tkms);
                    printf("%.2f\n",price);
                    break;
                case'b':
                case'B':
                    price=ammountDueB(days, tkms);
                    printf("%.2f\n",price);
                    break;
                case'c':
                case'C':
                    price=ammountDueC(days, tkms);
                    printf("%.2f\n",price);
        }

        printf("Select rental program.('Q' or 'q' to exit)\n");



        scanf("%s",&catcode);


    }while(catcode==!'Q'&&catcode==!'q');
    printf("%c",catcode);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the `==!` operator supposed to do?

Comment: `catcode==!'Q'` should be `catcode!='Q'`

Comment: for inequality expression you should use `!=` instead of `==!`. For example :         `int x = 0; if(x != 10) { /* TODO */ }`

Comment: if you want **catcode** to be string , then declare it as ' char catcode[]; '

Comment: You mean do{}(while);...

Comment: @ch3rub7: Do you come from Java? Declaring it as `char catcode[]` is... well... nonsense in C. GCC (at least) throws a warning stating that it holds a single element.

Comment: then he mentioned in the question that he wanted %s for catcode above while loop @KemyLand

Comment: @ch3rub7: But it's not valid C, neither the OP understood (at the moment) the implications of using `"%s"`...

Answer (score 1):

By "not working", I suppose you mean that it never enters a second iteration, but that is exactly what it is supposed to do.  `catcode==!'Q'&&catcode==!'q'` is true if `catcode` is equal to `!'Q'` and equal to `!'q'`.  `'Q'` is some non-zero integer (depends on your system, but is probably 81), and `!'Q'` is zero.  Similarly, `!'q'` is zero.  `catcode` isn't zero, so the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

First of all, the specifiers in `scanf`...

```
scanf("%s", &catcode);
```

This won't work. The `"%s"` specifier expects its corresponding argument to be a `char*` to a buffer of unspecified length (i.e: this has [the same problem as `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22419911/5249858)). You probably meant `"%c"`, whose corresponding argument shall point to *a single character*. Now, your format specifier is not recommended to be `"%c"`, but `" %c", because that extra space indicates`scanf()`to ignore all whitespace it can before`"%c"`. So, that line becomes...

```
scanf(" %c", &catcode);
```

Now, you're right, there's a problem in your `while` loop:

```
while(catcode==!'Q'&&catcode==!'q');
```

Let's "expand" this with whitespace, to make what you (apparently) intended more obvious (that's reason #1 to use spaces between operators!)...

```
while(catcode ==! 'Q' && catcode ==! 'q');
```

For you it appears okay. Not for me. The C language does not define any operator `==!`, rather, it defines operator `==` (that compares for equality), and operator `!` (that negates its single operand). The compiler would have understood that line as...

```
while(catcode == !'Q' && catcode == !'q');
```

Now, what does that mean? If the operand is non-zero, the `!` operator returns zero (in this case, the null character, `'\0'`). Otherwise, it returns a non-negative value (usually `1` (does the standard mandates this?)). Because `'Q'` is not `'\0'`, and same for `'q'`, that means that your loop is effectively...

```
while(catcode == '\0' && catcode == '\0'); // Think of '\0' as 0
```

Absolute non-sense expressed in code! The solution is to simply use operator `!=` (compares for inequality)...

```
while(catcode != 'Q' && catcode != 'q');
```

I hope this has led some light on you!