# String with empty spaces in C gets truncated

Tags: c, arrays, string, variables, spaces

I want to create an empty string with fixed length lets say 100 and then enter user input for that string , For some reason when I try to scan the string the code isnt showing me all the leading empty spaces after the user input .
If my empty string is of length 20 and input is 5 character then the count should be 20 . Am I missing something very basic here or the compiler truncates the empty spaces no matter what ?

```
int main () 
{
int count=0;
   char word[20];
   printf("Please enter a sting: ");
   scanf("%s", word);

   while (word[count]!= '\0' )
       {
       printf  ("%c",word[count]) ;
       count++;
       }
   printf ("\nCharacter count :%i\n", count);

}
```

The output is :

```
Please enter a sting: Words
Words
Character count :5

Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Why should the count be `20` if the input is 5-long, again? `scanf` will terminate the inputted 5 characters with `\0`, not spaces.

Comment: `scanf("%s", word);` skips leading whitespace, and stops at next whitespace. Time to read the man page? That is not the compiler's doing, it's the runtime code behaviour. The defined string length is only the *available* space - which will be overrun if you enter anything longer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Becuase I declared the string to be of length 20 and input is 5 , so there should be 20 in total .

Comment: Looks like a serious misconception about strings and I/O. Joining @WeatherVane suggestion.

Comment: @WeatherVane So how do I accomplish the objective of having a fixed length string and then I can fill it up with whatever I want leaving me with empty spaces in the end ?

Comment: This is the difference between `strlen()` and `sizeof` a `char` array.

Comment: @Fenomatik there is not only `scanf` function to read the input. check also getc, getchar, gets, fread...

Comment: @Serge I almost upvoted you, but you said `gets`, which must never, ever be used. This however↓, is upvote-worthy.

Comment: There may be a `scanf` format which will do that, others might advise, but you could also experiment with `fgets` using `stdin` which not only keeps leading and trailing spaces, but also the final `newline` which you would have to remove.

Comment: as @Medinoc pointed out check also why you should avoid `gets`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419866/is-the-gets-string-function-in-c-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: If you want to print the string in a field of width 20, left justified, blank padded, then `printf("[%-20s]\n", "words");` will do the job.  The square brackets make the result visible; the `-` is for left-justified; the 20 says the width must be at least 20 characters.  If you want at most 20 characters, you can use `printf("[%-20.20s]\n", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");` to limit the output to at most (as well as at least) 20 characters, left justified.  See [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Typically `scanf("%s", word);` reads but does not save leading white-space and then saves non-white-space characters to `word`.  It then appends a null character and returns.

To read a *line* of user input, including space character, use `fgets()`.  This will usually include the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'`.

```
 char word[20]; // Or maybe 100
 if (fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin)) {

   while (word[count]!= '\0') {
     printf("%c", word[count]);
     count++;
   }
   printf ("\nCharacter count :%i\n", count);
 }
```

> If my empty string is of length 20 and input is 5 character then the count should be 20 .

The count will reflect the number of characters entered *up to* 20 - 1 or 19.

Comment: Note that the array of size 20 can only hold 19 characters plus the null terminator reliably.  The count should never reach 20.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Right you are.  Unless that was 20 drinks - then who knows?

Comment: After 20 drinks, anything is possible — but liver rot seems high on the likelihood list, assuming they're alcoholic.  Otherwise, you're likely to need to make a lot of visits to a small room.